# How to use a package installed from npm in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, npm, composer-php

I'm sorry to ask this simple question. I'm completely new to package managers, npm in particular. Normally, what I use is linking my CSS/Scripts to CDN's

In this case, I'm wirtting a Laravel app which will need a bit more advanced `<select>`, so I decided to try [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) which covers my requirements.

Before trying npm or composer I tried the CDN way, but there was a file missing, so it didn't work.

In the documentation, there are several ways to install it, one is via npm:

```
npm install bootstrap-select
```

Other will be via composer:

```
composer require snapappointments/bootstrap-select
```

After it finishes installing, I check in my `/vendor` folder, and yes, there's a `snapappointments` with several folders beneath.

So... now what?

How do I link my CSS to this freshly installed package? same goes to scripts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this way is by using `npm` after you run the command `npm install bootstrap-select`

then go to `/resources/assets/sass/app.scss` to import the **SCSS** file
you will import it like that:

`@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss";`

after that you need to add also the js file in, go to this path:
 `resources/assets/js/app.js`

and import js files like that
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select');

**At Last:**
run this command `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` to make a compiled css&js file

> `npm run watch` run compile your files every time you hit save 
>     `npm run dev` to compile your files on time

and import it to your app blade using `asset` helper function like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app,js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: When adding a JS module in `app.js`, you can use `~` as a synonym of the `node_modules` directory location. So the require can be simpler: `require('~bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select');`.

Comment: @AugustoMoura that did not work for me. I had to specify the full URI the way Joseph had originally stated.